# Basic Inheritance help in Java

Tags: java

I am new to Java and I am trying to grow my knowledge. I am currently stuck on an Assignment that involves Basic inheritance.  This is my code and my output will be tested with different names. I cant seem to get an iutput at all. I have looked up videos on Onheritance but none have seem to be helpful in my case. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class StudentDerivationFromPerson {
   public static void main (String [] args) {
      StudentData courseStudent = new StudentData();

      courseStudent.printAll();
      System.out.println(", ID: " + courseStudent.setID());

   }
}
```

and here is the entire code

```
// ===== Code from file PersonData.java =====
public class PersonData {
   private int ageYears;
   private String lastName;

   public void setName(String userName) {
      lastName  = userName;
   }

   public void setAge(int numYears) {
      ageYears = numYears;
   }

   // Other parts omitted

   public void printAll() {
      System.out.print("Name: " + lastName);
      System.out.print(", Age: "  + ageYears);
   }
}
// ===== end =====

// ===== Code from file StudentData.java =====
public class StudentData extends PersonData {
   private int idNum;

   public void setID(int studentId) {
      idNum = studentId;
   }

   public int getID() {
      return idNum;
   }
}
// ===== end =====

// ===== Code from file StudentDerivationFromPerson.java =====
public class StudentDerivationFromPerson {
   public static void main (String [] args) {
      StudentData courseStudent = new StudentData();

      courseStudent.printAll();
      System.out.println(", ID: " + courseStudent.setID());

   }
}
// ===== end =====
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and reword your post. It seems you forgot to actually ask a question. What are you having trouble with, and how does your code's behaviour differ from what you expected it to do?

Comment: Do you have an issue with overriding `printAll` method in `StudentData` class?

Comment: courseSudent variable is initialized to nothing. It won't print a thing. You are calling setID in the println. It's useless as it returns void. And above all, what is your issue ? What do you want us to do ? Validate what you did ? Explain ?

Comment: You don't put any data in the objects.

Answer (score 0):

Method `printAll` should be overridden in `StudentData` class, using call to `super.printAll()` to reuse and print person data:

```
public class StudentData extends PersonData {
    private int idNum;

    public void setID(int studentId) {
        idNum = studentId;
    }

    public int getID() {
        return idNum;
    }

    @Override
    public void printAll() {
        super.printAll();
        System.out.println(", ID: " + idNum);
    }
}
```

Then the following example

```
public class StudentDerivationFromPerson {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        StudentData courseStudent = new StudentData();
        courseStudent.setName("Doe");
        courseStudent.setAge(21);
        courseStudent.setID(1001);
        courseStudent.printAll();
    }
}
```

prints:

```
Name: Doe, Age: 21, ID: 1001
```